# HTML5 drag event not firing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg

I have the following in an HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width='570' height='500' style='border: 2px solid #000;'>
      <rect id='test-rect' class='a-rect' draggable='true' 
        stroke-width='1' stroke='#000' fill='#fff' 
        ry='10' rx='10' r='10' 
        height='119' width='168' y='169' x='282'>
      </rect>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the following in `test.js`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var elem = document.getElementById('test-rect');

    elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
        console.log('You mouse-downed on a \' SVG node!', event);
    });

    elem.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'all';
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', 'node');
        console.log('And now you\'re DRAGGIN\' a SVG node!', event);
    });

    elem.addEventListener('drag', function (event) {
        console.log('Still doin\' it!', event);
    });

    elem.addEventListener('dragend', function (event) {
        console.log('Done!', event);
    });
});
```

The `mousedown` and `dragstart` events are firing properly, but neither the `drag` nor `dragend` are doing the same. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920345/html-drag-event-does-not-fire-in-firefox) from about a year ago that suggests I must call `setData` in order to have `drag` fire, but that didn't do it.

How do I go about getting a proper HTML5 `drag`, and more importantly, `dragend` event triggering on an SVG node in Firefox?

Comment: I've attempted this before. Unfortunately HTML5 drag events are not supported on SVG Elements (at least not in Firefox or Webkit).

Comment: I had problems with drag and svg as well (check various Browsers as well, as some have different implementations), so implemented my own using mousedown, checking for that when mousemove event is handled.