# e.originalEvent.pageX and e.originalEvent.pageY are always zero when dragging a div in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm dragging a div using drag API but `e.originalEvent.pageX` and `e.originalEvent.pageY` always return 0.
`.container` div can only be dragged using the red square, that's why it can't have draggable attribute from the beginning.

This is my code:

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="dragger"></div>
</div>
<label></label>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.container').on('drag', function(e){
        $('label').text("pageX:" + e.originalEvent.pageX + " pageY:" + e.originalEvent.pageY);
        console.log("pageX:" + e.originalEvent.pageX + " pageY:" + e.originalEvent.pageY);
    }).on('dragstart', function(e){
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'junk');
    });

    $('.dragger').on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).parent().attr('draggable', 'true');
    }).on('mouseout', function(){
        $(this).parent().removeAttr('draggable');        
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    background: #ccc;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

.dragger {
    position:absolute;
    top:-8px;
    right:-8px;
    background: red;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}
```

And this is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gypLrxvq/

**EDIT**

I've found a workaround to get that coordinates:

```
var pageX = 0;
var pageY = 0;
$(document).on("dragover",function(e) {
    pageX = e.originalEvent.pageX; 
    pageY = e.originalEvent.pageY;
});
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work in Firefox for me (I never see text in the label), but it works fine in Chrome (and the label is updated with non-zero coordinates).

Comment: @Pointy in Firefox if you drag the element using the red square the label text will appear

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't for me.

Comment: @Pointy try using console.log(); instead of $('label').text()

Comment: Looks like a long lasting Firefox bug. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13920345/3168107

Comment: [Here's the bug in the Firefox bugzilla.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521)

Comment: It's probably not even a bug per se, they just define the event differently - and inconveniently. They use `drag` as `originalEvent`, where Chrome uses `MouseEvent` with a type of `drag`.

Comment: Can I do something to get that coordinates? I appreciate any help, I thank you for all comments.

Comment: I see you found the only solution available already.